# Calling subproject binary with system() function 4 times faster than linking subproject

Tags: c++, performance, system

I need to call a subproject from a main project and implemented two ways of doing that. 
It turns out, that the second way is a factor 4 slower than the first. 
Can anybody explain this to me?

The subproject looks like this:

```
#include "fancyProject.h"
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string controlFile = argv[1];
  return runFancyProject(controlFile);
}
```

First way: Call the binary of the subproject in the main project via the system() function:

```
std::string command = "fancyProject controlFile.dat";
int result = system(command.c_str());
```

Second way: Create a library from the subproject, link this library with the main project and call the specific function:

```
#include "fancyProject.h"
std::string controlFile = "controlFile.dat";
int result = runFancyProject(controlFile);
```

In the meantime, I created a [minimal example](http://gofile.me/2ksJo/CtqHKcvAb). However, it behaves as expected: The system() function is slower than the call of the linked function. Thus, the error has to be somewhere else in the project. Nevertheless thank you very much for your time, especially to dsboger. I will do further investigations in this direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "directly link"?

Comment: What operating system? Have you tried to profile your application to find out what's taking so much time when statically linked? (If you're not using a profiler, how do you know it's 4x faster?) How much faster is 4x -- are talking microseconds or seconds?

Comment: Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I tested it on macOS and ubuntu. So far, I didn't use a sophisticated profiler and just measured the wall time. We are talking seconds (900 compared to 3600)

Comment: Ok, I try to setup a minimal example.

Comment: Well, what is your process doing during all that extra time?

Comment: It is odd that spawning a new process is faster than making a function call. One reason I can think of is multi-threading: if your main project and subproject are in different threads that share variables, running in a different process will create a copy of the shared variables and reduce synchronization.

Comment: This is a good hint. I'm sorry that I forgot to mention, that the main project indeed calls parallel versions of the subproject